# Given a string how to find start and end index of all non-whitespace substrings in python

Tags: python, string, substring

Given a string:

```
?           ^^^^    ^^^  --
```

How can I find the start and end index of all substrings after the first character?

Expected output: `(12,15), (20,22), (25,26)`

I tried the following but it only works for the first substring not the rest:

```
string = '?           ^^^^    ^^^  --'
index = len(string ) - len(string .lstrip())
```

Comment: Presumably by "substring" you actually mean "sequence of one or more adjacent non-space characters"?

Comment: yes @JohnGordon that would be a more apt way of putting it

Comment: Using regex would probably be easiest here, especially since you want the start and end indexes too. Something like `re.findall('\S+', string[1:])`.

Comment: use a regular expression `\S+` and the `re.finditer()` and then `matchObj.span()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match any sequence of non-whitespace. The `Match` object contains the start and end index of each match.

```
import re
string = '?           ^^^^    ^^^  --'
result = [(m.start(), m.end()-1) for m in re.finditer(r'\S+', string)][1:]
```

The `[1:]` removes the match of `?` at the beginning.

I had to substract 1 from `m.end()` because it points to the index *after* the match (so that using the start and end as a range will get the whole match).

If the first substring can be immediately after `?`, you need to slice the string first, and then add 1 to the start index rather than subtracting from the end index, to adjust for the missing first character.

```
result = [(m.start()+1, m.end()) for m in re.finditer(r'\S+', string[1:])]
```